# How to prevent overloading the queue when using annotation based SpringBoot ThreadPoolTaskExecutor?

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot

I have an annotation based spring boot application which has a lot of data processing done and storing the results in a database, which I would like to be multi threaded in order to increase the speed.

My problem is that once the work queue has been completely filled and the asynchronous method is called again, I get a `TaskRejectedException` caused by a `RejectedExecutionException`. At that point, the currently queued tasks do complete, but additional are no longer queued. The amount of data to be processed is pretty large, so I cannot remove the limit of queue capacity, as the application would run out of usable memory.

I would like to be able to back off and retry after a given amount of time if the task queue is at its limit, and I need help on how to do that. I describe my current setup below.

Async is enabled in my Application class and I am creating a `TaskExecutor` using annotations.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com")
@EnableAsync
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

...

@Bean
@Qualifier("parallelExecutor")
public TaskExecutor parallelExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(10);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Parallel Executor");
    return executor;
}
```

I am using an `@Async` annotation to declare my data processing and database storing method as asynchronous and to be multithreaded.

```
@Async("parallelExecutor")
public void processAndStoreData(JsonObject item);
```

I am looping through all the data to be processed in a separate class which calls the asynchronous method.

```
for (int j = 0; j < items.size(); i++) {
    // Each JsonObject
    dataStoreService.processAndStoreData(items.get(j).getAsJsonObject());
}
```

Comment: Your loop is fast if you have 20 rows it already breaks. You can proces 4 concurrently and have another 10 waiting. If you have a lot of processing and want a more robust proces use Spring Batch. Also single threading might even be faster as you can do everything in a single transaction with a single db connection. Now you have the overhead of a lot of transactions etc.

Comment: Looping through the items does occur quite quickly, the slow part is the processAndStoreData method. There are a LOT of items which is why the taskQueue breaks easily.
I am using Spring Data JPA CrudRepository for persistence. The processing of each individual item involves multiple inserts to multiple different tables.
I attempted multi threading  to move the bottleneck from database persistence latency to data processing overhead.I'll look into spring batch.

Comment: As stated multithreading might even worsen the performance. The bottleneck is your database you now also have the overhead of multiple transactions. Instead of making things more complex make it simpler. Use a single thread (do the processing in the for loop) and do proper batch processing with JPA (clearing and flushing the entity manager from time to time). Resorting to multi threading should be a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled spring boot async? Maybe you should add TaskExecutorConfig. You can try

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class TaskExecutorConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

    //重写getAsyncExcutor方法，并返回一个基于线程池的TaskExecutor
    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(10);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Parallel Executor");
    return executor;
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question to reflect how I have currently enabled Spring Boot Async. I can confirm that my tasks are in fact being performed asynchronously, the problem is once the tasks exceed the TaskExecutor queue size, I get an exception and no additional tasks are queued.

Comment: I made a separate class with your snip, and it did not seem to help, even after adding the @Qualifier("parallelExecutor") to the executor method.
I'm guess I'm not sure how to hook this up.

Comment: sorry,i have made a mistake before, for your problem ,there is not enough thread work for your large data in process, the solution is increase pool size if available or slow down your data in process speed

Comment: if data in item is not large , you can consider storeData at once with batch,rather than  multi threading,just like this
`
for (int j = 0; j < items.size(); i++) {
    // Each JsonObject
    List.add(target)
}
dataStoreService.processAndStoreDataBatch(list);
`